Unity Text on Each other
this is my AdminUI.cs
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class AdminUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI userPrefab; // TextMeshProUGUI prefab for user email and username
    public Transform contentPanel; // Panel to which the TextMeshPro components will be attached

    async void Start()
    {
        // Fetch user data from the database
        string usersText = await Getusers.GetUsersText();

        // Split the received text by newline character
        string[] lines = usersText.Split('\n');

        // Display user data using TextMeshPro
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Instantiate TextMeshPro component for user email and username
            TextMeshProUGUI userText = Instantiate(userPrefab, contentPanel);

            // Set the user email and username text
            userText.text = line;
        }
    }
}

public static class Getusers
{
    readonly static string SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:80/Cryppy";

    public static async Task<string> GetUsersText()
    {
        string GET_USERS_URL = $"{SERVER_URL}/GetUsers.php";
        UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get(GET_USERS_URL);

        // Send the request asynchronously
        var operation = req.SendWebRequest();

        // Wait until the request is completed
        while (!operation.isDone)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100); // You can adjust the delay time as needed
        }

        // Check for errors
        if (req.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error fetching users: {req.error}");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Return the response text
            return req.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }


}


and this is the GetUser.php
<?php
// Connect to your database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cryppy_nightfall";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch user data
$sql = "SELECT email, username FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if any rows were returned
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $users = "";
    // Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Concatenate email and username with a colon and line break
        $user = $row["email"] . ":" . $row["username"] . "\n";
        $users .= $user;
    }
    
    // Return the string
    echo $users;
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
     

in the website , the data displayed good
but in unity when lunch , the data display on each other so you can't even read
tried to add  to the php
and tried \n to the script
but not worked
btw am using scroll view , so this info should be dispalyed in UI screen

Well, \n on windows is only half of a line feed, but, by OS it can vary.

I would remove the PHP tag, PHP has nothing to do with the subject.

The problem comes by the wrong assumption that contentPanel is a sort of list container that is able to dispose children as a list. contentPanel is actually a Transform object, that is a position in the coordinates system, so there is no surprise that all TextMeshProUGUI are placed at the same location.
You have to move the transform by some vertical offset at each iteration to make each line appears after the previous one.
The Instantiate method in Unity reference has an example of how to do this using Vector instead of Transform, but the concept is the same:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}

I guess the better option would be the complete overload which allows to set both parent transform and a Vector offset:
Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent)

I would try this:
int i = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Instantiate TextMeshPro component for user email and username
    TextMeshProUGUI userText = Instantiate(userPrefab, new Vector3(0, i * 10f, 0), Quaternion.identity, contentPanel);

    // Set the user email and username text
    userText.text = line;
    i++;
}

